# Curl on latest ubuntu and debian container image on Docker Desktop 3.4.0 on Mac M1 results in segmentation fault

Tags: docker, ubuntu, segmentation-fault, apple-m1

I have an issue on my Mac M1 with Big Sur 11.4 and Docker Desktop 3.4.0 installed
When i run a ubuntu container and want to curl for an .sh script it results in a segmentation fault.

**If i go back to the older debian:18.04 image it works without issue.**

For the latest Ubuntu Image:

Error message:

```
root@67e8d5468e90:/# curl https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
Segmentation fault
```

Same for wget:

```
root@67e8d5468e90:/# wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
    --2021-06-21 08:38:36--  https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
    Resolving repo.anaconda.com (repo.anaconda.com)... 104.16.130.3, 104.16.131.3, 2606:4700::6810:8203, ...
    Connecting to repo.anaconda.com (repo.anaconda.com)|104.16.130.3|:443... connected.
    Segmentation fault
```

Container Details:

```
root@67e8d5468e90:/# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Comment: As it is, this looks like it would be better as a bug report. It might be the 'known issue' listed here https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/release-notes/. Have you tried in Ubuntu 21.04?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the hint! It actually works with 21.04.

Comment: Did you have any luck with it? Great idea testing curl and wget. I assumed my issue was curl related, but if wget is having a problem, then perhaps it's an ssl lib issue?